# aws-vault: prompt for pass password if necessary

Tags: passwords, amazon-web-services, gnupg, credentials, gpg-agent

I'm using pass as a backend to aws-vault on a remote machine and it seems like I need to manually add the "password" for the profile into gpg-agent before aws-vault can make use of it. Without first decrypting the password it would give the error

```
$ aws-vault exec --no-session --debug default -- aws s3 ls
2023/02/02 19:35:53 aws-vault v6.6.2
2023/02/02 19:35:53 Loading config file /home/<user>/.aws/config
2023/02/02 19:35:53 Parsing config file /home/<user>/.aws/config
2023/02/02 19:35:53 [keyring] Considering backends: [pass]
2023/02/02 19:35:53 profile default: using stored credentials
2023/02/02 19:35:53 profile default: skipping GetSessionToken because disabled
2023/02/02 19:35:53 Looking up keyring for 'default'
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
aws-vault: error: exec: Failed to get credentials for default: exit status 2
```

but after running `pass default` and entering the `pass` password it then works since (I'm guessing) the credentials are now stored in gpg-agent for some time and aws-vault can see them properly.

How can I get aws-vault to prompt for the pass password if it requires it? Rather than having to run `pass <profile>` first.

Comment: Ultimately I found out that trying to unlock an already unlocked pass secret is just a no-op so I can add an alias to always try to unlock it and I'll only be prompted if need be.

Answer (score 1):

you can use AWS_VAULT_FILE_PASSPHRASE environment variable to pass the passphrase. see the documentation here https://github.com/99designs/aws-vault/blob/master/USAGE.md#environment-variables

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).